# How to get count of two columns of a table based on PK of another table?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables defined as:

```
CREATE TABLE airports (
  code char(3) not null primary key,
  name varchar(100) not null,
  city varchar(50) not null,
  state varchar(5),
  country char(2) not null references fcountries(code)
)
```

and

```
CREATE TABLE flights (
  departure char(3) not null references airports(code), -- airport code
  arrival char(3) not null references airports(code), -- airport code
  dep_time time not null,
  airline char(2) not null references airlines(code)
)
```

I need to get the number of flights departing from and arriving at an airport using postgres. So, I wrote

```
select
  code,
  count(departure)
from airports 
join flights 
 on flights.departure = airports.code group by code;
```

and for departure similarily,

```
select
  code,
  count(arrival) as Arrival
from airports 
join flights 
  on flights.arrival = airports.code group by code;
```

But I need to combine these two and get the arrival-departure count in the same result. I am not sure how to do it?
I wrote this query

```
select
  code,
  count(departure),
  x.arrival
from (
  select count(arrival) as arrival
  from airports 
  join flights 
    on flights.arrival = airports.code group by code
) x, 
airports 
join flights on airports.code = flights.departure
group by code, x.arrival
order by code;
```

But the result is not correct as 'code' is repeated in this result. I am pretty new to sql and not sure how to write this.

Comment: update your question add that the related  tables schema a proper data sample  and the expected  result

Comment: and decide about the DBMS please.

Comment: typo i guess. `group by code` instead of `roup by code`

Comment: that I changed still the error is there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think alias t2 cannot be used like that after join that's why you are getting the error. Try this:

`select t1.code,  t1.count_departure, t2.count_arrival
    from (
        select code, count(departure)  count_departure
        from airports join flights on flights.departure = airports.code
        group by code
    ) t1
     join  (
        select code, count(arrival) as  count_arrival
        from airports join flights on flights.arrival = airports.code
        group by code
    ) t2 on t1.code  = t2.code;`

Answer (score 1):

The simplest method is a lateral join and `group by`:

```
select v.code, count(*) as total,
       sum(is_departure) as num_departures,
       sum(is_arrival) as num_arrivals
from flights cross join lateral
     (values (departure, 1, 0), (arrival, 0, 1)
     ) as v(code, is_departure, is_rrival)
     on f.departure = a.code
group by v.code;
```

Note that the `JOIN` to `airports` is unnecessary, unless you actually want to bring in more information that you haven't mentioned in the question.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the two query as  subquery and join

```
    select t1.code,  t1.count_departure, t2.count_arrival 
    from (
        select code, count(departure)  count_departure
        from airports join flights on flights.departure = airports.code 
        group by code

    ) t1  
    inner join  (
        select code, count(arrival) as  count_arrival 
        from airports join flights on flights.arrival = airports.code 
        roup by code

    ) t2 on t1.code  = t2.code ;
```

Comment: this gives error "syntax error near select" that is select after t2(select code....) I don't know why?

Comment: answer  updated .. wrong position fo rtable  alias name

Answer (score 0):

A quite simple method is just to use a correlated COUNT subquery in the SELECT clause:

```
select a.code,
    (select count(*) from flights f where f.departure = a.code) as departures,
    (select count(*) from flights f where f.arrival = a.code) as arrivals
from airports a;
```